# Combining "during" with present perfect tense

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

I have a question about how to combine the use of the word *during* with a verb in the present perfect tense. The sentence is:

> During this period, I have successfully spotted trends, patterns and hidden insights by exploring data sets of any size.

By using *During this period* I specify that I mean my current work experience, which is ongoing.

Is my sentence grammatically correct?

If not, then would replacing *During this period* with, for instance, *In my current role* make the sentence correct?

Comment: Since you are speaking now and up to the present time, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would *In my current role* and *In the last two years* be okay too?

Comment: You might try **In my ongoing work I have successfully ...** or **For the past 2 years my ongoing work has successfully included spotting ...**

Comment: Is *work* sufficient or is *work experience* conceptually better?

Comment: During this period, in my current role, and in the last two years are all perfectly fine. I don't know why people propose alternatives when you're asking whether your own proposals are correct and, in fact, they are.